# PHP/mysql checking all dates are accounted for

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an app where I want the users to enter a job history. I store the results in a mysql table using the DATE format (start_date and end_date for each job). So for instance, after a couple entries it could look like this (job_history table:

```
Job             Start              End
Dishwasher      2013-07-10         2014-03-28
Banker          2014-04-02         2014-10-10
Cahsier         2014-10-11         2014-12-20
```

I'm trying to set up a mysql query that will check to see if there are any missing days from a certain year. For our example, lets use 2014. There are missing days from 2014-03-29 to 2014-04-01.

I haven't been able to find any good examples by searching. I figured there would be a better way to do it than doing a PHP loop and doing 365 queries (ouch!). Thanks

Edit: Updated example to incorporate year beginning and year end:

```
Job             Start              End
Dishwasher      2013-07-10         2013-12-01
Banker          2014-01-10         2014-10-10
Cahsier         2014-10-11         2014-12-20
```

In this example our input year would be 2014 and we would have 9 days at the beginning of the year that are uncovered, and 11 at the end of the year.

Comment: why not use mysql `DISTINCT` and then loop through the results looking for any missing dates in php.  It would still be one query but you can manage the logic in php code.

Comment: Are there always only 3 job types? Eg Dishwasher, Banker and Cashier? If so, you could probably create a crosstab query and then work on than.

Comment: do you have a unique identifier column? like an ID in the table that is the primary key?

Comment: The DISTINCT idea is interesting, may try that unless something better comes along. There can be unlimited number of Job types. YES, I have a unique ID column

Comment: If there is an unlimited number of job types, a crosstab won't work so I agree with Chuck's suggestion. Why would it be looping 365 queries?

Comment: How do I use mysql DISTINCT to loop though the dates in the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming to this question later, the original answer was this

```
SELECT jh.id,
    CASE
        WHEN datediff(jh1.start, jh.end) > 1
        THEN datediff(jh1.start, jh.end)
        ELSE NULL
    END as DifferenceInDays
FROM job_history jh
LEFT JOIN job_history jh1 ON jh1.id = (jh.id + 1)
```

what this does is it assumes a sequential id to self join to, that way you can compare the last rows date with the current rows date.

After a lot of additions to the requirements this will do what you want.

```
SELECT position, id, DifferenceInDays
FROM
(       SELECT 'BEGINNING' as position, id,
            @a := if(@a = 'BAD', 'BAD', if(DATE(concat(year(now()), '-01-01')) BETWEEN start AND end, 'BAD', '')),
            case
                WHEN @a = 'BAD'
                THEN NULL
                ELSE datediff(jstart, DATE(concat(year(now()), '-01-01')))
            end AS DifferenceInDays
        FROM
        (   SELECT jh.*, jh3.start as jstart
            FROM job_history jh
            CROSS JOIN(SELECT @a:='')t
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT min(start) as start FROM job_history where userid = 123456 AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(NOW())) jh3 ON jh3.start = jh.start
            WHERE jh.userid = 123456
            ORDER BY id
        )t
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'MIDDLE', jh.id, '',
            case
                WHEN datediff(jh1.start, jh.end) > 1
                THEN datediff(jh1.start, jh.end) - 1
                ELSE NULL
            end as DifferenceInDays
        FROM
        (   SELECT *, @new_id := @new_id + 1 as new_id
            FROM job_history, (select @new_id := 0) temp
            WHERE userid = 123456
        ) jh
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT *, @new_id1 := @new_id1 + 1 as new_id
            FROM job_history, (select @new_id1 := 0) temp
            WHERE userid = 123456
        ) jh1 ON jh1.new_id = (jh.new_id + 1)

    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ENDING', id, 
            @b := if(@b = 'BAD', 'BAD', if(DATE(concat(year(now()), '-12-31')) BETWEEN start AND end, 'BAD', '')),
            case
                WHEN @b = 'BAD'
                THEN NULL
                ELSE datediff(DATE(concat(year(now()), '-12-31')), jend)
            end
        FROM
        (   SELECT jh.*, jh2.end as jend
            FROM job_history jh
            CROSS JOIN(SELECT @b:='')t
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(end) as end FROM job_history WHERE userid = 123456) jh2 ON jh2.end = jh.end
            WHERE jh.userid = 123456
            ORDER BY id
        )t
    ORDER BY case position WHEN 'BEGINNING' THEN 1 WHEN 'MIDDLE' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ASC, id ASC
) t
WHERE DifferenceInDays IS NOT NULL
```

[**FIDDLE WITH MULTIPLE ROWS**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2f04/1)

[**FIDDLE WITH ONLY MIDDLE AND END**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc71/3)

[**FIDDLE WITH NO MIDDLE ONE ROW**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d39f/1)

[**FIDDLE WITH ALL THREE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87a6e/2)

[**FIDDLE WITH NO END**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ba32/1)

Comment: Thanks for that and the fiddle. But if I change the last job to end at 2014-12-20 instead of 2014-12-31, the missing days at the end of the year aren't accounted for with this method

Comment: @phpmysqlguy that is a different requirement. how do you determine which year to use? you have from 2013 to 2014. I can include up to the current_day if you want, but what is the requirement? the end of the current year? the end of the next year?

Comment: @phpmysqlguy see my edit for a way to include up to the current year.

Comment: Think your on the right track, awesome stuff (and thanks). However with your latest version I updated your fiddle and I edited my original post to reflect the end of the year not being covered (ends 2014-12-20). In the example it should return 4 and then 11 days at the end. I think your code is returning 4 and then 10.

Comment: @phpmysqlguy run this. `select datediff('2014-12-31', '2014-12-20'), datediff('2014-04-02','2014-03-28')` you will see that it is handled inclusively on both. i did a minus 1 on both to return the number of days not inclusively

Comment: Great stuff... one last thing, the beginning of the year. I updated my question to reflect the handling of the stuff at the start of the year as well.

Comment: Getting some odd behavior with your query if there are only two rows in the table. Doesn't seem to work right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc71/1

Comment: @phpmysqlguy are you only going to have 2 rows? the issue is because it is the last to compare the end of the year to as well as the day with a gap on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67579/discussion-between-phpmysqlguy-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: @phpmysqlguy did that fix your issue?

Comment: Wow amazing work. I've done a few minutes of testing, will do more tomorrow. The only thing is having the middle be non-inclusive. It looks like the beginning and end are. For instance: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87a6e/2 ... how to make the middle 6 to just count days between them, not including either day. I looked at the code for 15 minutes but I am in over my head trying to make this simple change!

Comment: @phpmysqlguy sure thing. all you need to do for that is this [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87a6e/3)

Comment: @phpmysqlguy edited to include the userid. see the chat for more info

Comment: this is a great query, but as we discussed unfortunately the id's have to be sequential for it to work. So it's going to have pretty limiting uses

Comment: @phpmysqlguy see my most recent update for a way to have the id's to not be sequential

Comment: Awesome stuff here. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -2):

You can  [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function for finding difference between two date

```
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

Comment: I know about date_diff, but don't see how this answers the question